# Hide facebook like box IFRAME component

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook-like

Is it possible to hide the text "Facebook social module" in Facebook IFRAME like box ?

[image: I'm using IFRAME]

**Ps:** The text div belong to a class "clearfix pvs phm" so here is what I tried in my CSS:

```
.clearfix.pvs.phm{visibility:hidden;}

<!-- HTML -->
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FFacebookDevelopers&amp;width=180&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=false&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:180px; height:258px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: If ur using I-frame plugin.. you cant hide it you need to use `html5` code to apply your css

Answer (score 0):

Sure. First of all, find it's div, table etc. via DOM. Second, add css it's div id (for example face-social), class etc. to these lines;

```
#face-social{
display: none;
}
```

if you don't like that solution. You must try iframe. That's why you have to use again CSS and iframe width, height values.

Edit: Change it to;

```
.clearfix.pvs.phm
{display:none
}
```

Comment: add: .pvs {display: none;}

Comment: Doesn't work...I added the IFRAME code to the question.

Comment: Please change iframe height; <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FFacebookDevelopers&amp;width=180&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=false&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:180px; height:230px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>